# tf.keras.backend.get_session() and keras.backend.get_session() return different session objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've noticed that tf.keras.backend.get_session() and keras.backend.get_session() return different session objects.

Anyway to make sure they return the same object? I have some code that uses tf.keras.backend.get_session() to save a Keras model with tf.saved_model.simple_save but it throws an uninitialised error if the model comes from a library that uses keras instead of tensorflow.keras

Example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import ResNet50
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow.keras.backend as J

model = ResNet50()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(K.get_session())
print(J.get_session())
```

Answer (score 2):

You have bigger issues, you should not mix code using `keras` and `tf.keras`, these modules are **not compatible**, and you will get weird errors if you mix them.

If you really have a good reason to change the session, you can use `K.set_session` to set the session manually to the object returned by the other implementation.

Comment: I'm not mixing code. I just don't want to have to duplicate my low-level code that uses backend.get_session() for saving models. (e.g. when someone shares a some model code that is in keras and not tf.keras)

Comment: @geometrikal See update, but still you should be careful as unexpected things can happen.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro : Why does calling `tf.get_default_session`, while using`tf.keras` throw an error afterwards,if I use it  instead of `tf.keras.backend.get_session`? Aren't `tensorflow` and `tf.keras` compatible, I seem to be using `tf.get_default_graph` at another place, and I don't see any error for that.